# Interesting number theory question

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $n>7$ is an integer, then $n=3m+5n$ where $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$. Basically all integers greater than or equal to $8$ can be written in the form

$$3m+5n.$$

Is there a generalized result where if $(a,b)=1$ and $a+b=k$ then can any integer greater than $k$ be written as a linear combo of $a,b??$

Comment: Frobenius coin problem

Comment: This should be a duplicate.

Comment: sorry, people on here are mean. I did not know its a duplicate. its not my fault I'm younger and I stumble across mathematics later in life and you all have witnessed a lot of these tricks and tips of the trade, please do easy on us students. do not make this a toxic learning environment. I own/operate a discord where students cannot do basic algebra, how you think they'd feel if I just shook them off like people shake me off here. I hope someone on the board reads this and changes the rules to be more friendly all around.